# Reversing a file in Fortran

Tags: beginner, file, fortran

This is my first foray into (modern) Fortran in order to learn a bit more about the language, and I'm attempting the following problem: taking the path of an arbitrarily-sized text or binary file given as a command line argument, output to stdout the contents of the file in reverse (i.e. the first byte becomes the last). I would like to do this by reading the file sequentially into memory in chunks in one pass without using any seeks/rewinds etc.

It works (I think), and I'm interested in..

- better ways of working with arrays of pointers (to arrays), as used here with the dynamically sized array of `chunkptr`s. From what I've understood, it is necessary to make these additional types ([Arrays of Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900336/arrays-of-pointers)) and access through means of `chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array`. Perhaps there is some better approach?
- how best to perform error handling (should note I forgot to add checks here after the (de)allocates, I would do this in a similar way with `stat` and `errmsg` variables, similar to as in `open` )
- improvements related to code layout/organisation and use of subroutines and functions.

Any other comments or ideas also greatly appreciated.

```
! take a file and output it to stdout in reverse

program main
    use                                 :: iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

!!! constants
    integer, parameter                  :: CHUNK_SIZE           = 1024
    integer, parameter                  :: MIN_CHUNKS           = 1
    integer, parameter                  :: IN_FID               = 10

!!! type definitions
    type chunk 
        character, allocatable          :: chunk_array(:)
    endtype chunk

    type chunkptr
        type(chunk), pointer            :: ptr
    end type chunkptr

!!! locals
    character(len=256)                  :: path, io_msg
    integer                             :: total_bytes, num_chunks, i, status
    type(chunkptr), allocatable         :: chunks(:)

!!! begin program 
    call get_command_argument(1, path, status=status)
    if (status /= 0) then
        write (error_unit, *) "usage: ./reverse <file>" 
        call exit(1)
    end if

    allocate(chunks(MIN_CHUNKS))

    ! open, slurp file and close
    open(IN_FID, file=path, access="stream", iostat=status, iomsg=io_msg, status="old")
    if (status /= 0) then
        write (error_unit, *) trim(io_msg) 
        call exit(1)
    end if

    call slurp_file(IN_FID, num_chunks, total_bytes, chunks)   
    close(IN_FID)

    ! output in reverse, and print debug info
    call print_reversed(total_bytes, num_chunks, chunks)  
    write (error_unit, *) "reversed ", total_bytes, "bytes"

    ! free allocated resources
    do i=num_chunks, 1, -1
        deallocate(chunks(i)%ptr%chunk_array)
        deallocate(chunks(i)%ptr)
    end do

    deallocate(chunks)


contains
    subroutine slurp_file(fid, num_chunks, total, chunks) 
        integer                         :: fid, io_status = 0
        integer, intent(out)            :: total, num_chunks
        type(chunkptr), allocatable     :: chunks(:)

        num_chunks = 0
        total = 1

        do
            num_chunks = num_chunks + 1   
            call ensure_capacity(num_chunks, chunks)

            allocate(chunks(num_chunks)%ptr)
            allocate(chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array(CHUNK_SIZE))

            READ(fid, pos=total, iostat=io_status) chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array
            inquire(fid, pos=total)

            if (io_status == iostat_end) exit     
        end do     

        total = total - 1

    end subroutine slurp_file


    subroutine ensure_capacity(capacity, chunks)
        integer                                         :: capacity
        type(chunkptr), allocatable, intent(inout)      :: chunks(:)
        type(chunkptr), allocatable                     :: tmp(:)  

        if (capacity > size(chunks)) then
            allocate( tmp( 2*size(chunks)) )
            tmp(:size(chunks)) = chunks
            call move_alloc(tmp, chunks)
        end if   
    end subroutine ensure_capacity


    subroutine print_reversed(total_bytes, num_chunks, chunks)
        integer                     :: total_bytes, num_chunks, i, j
        type(chunkptr), allocatable :: chunks(:)

        ! last chunk may not be a multiple of CHUNK_SIZE...
        j = modulo(total_bytes, CHUNK_SIZE)

        do i = num_chunks, 1, -1
            do j=j, 1, -1
                call fputc(output_unit, chunks(i)%ptr%chunk_array(j))
            end do

            ! remaining chunks have size CHUNK_SIZE, however
            j = CHUNK_SIZE  
        end do
    end subroutine print_reversed

end program main
```

Comment: Any relation with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328728/in-fortran-how-to-write-backward-from-a-file-to-another-file-by-blocks-of-line/51329093#51329093 ?

Comment: Interesting, thanks I hadn't seen this. I think that question is interested in reversing the order of 'blocks' within a text file with a certain structure, whereas I'm just trying to reverse the byte order of any text or binary file. Additionally, the pure Fortran answer given there uses temporary files and I would like to load the file in its entirety into memory -  as an exercise to work with dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations. For a first try of Fortran that looks overall quite good, 
but of course there are some things to improve.

## General architecture

If you assume, that all chunks have always the same size, you could simply use a 2D character array. 
Since you have an array of chunks you can make the chunks unequally sized, then you can simply print them in the end without thinking about the different size of the last chunk.
You don't need the chunkptr type, but you are right in your understanding that you need a derived type, to have an array of pointers.
In addition if you use allocatables and not pointers, you can use automatic deallocation when variables go out of scope. 
Then you can get rid of your explicit deallocations.
As a general rule of thumb: Allocatable is always preferred over pointers for three reasons:

1. Allocatables have exclusive ownership unless you add the `target` qualifier. This makes it easier to reason about code.
2. Since the compiler can assume exclusive ownership, you get automatic deallocation when variables go out of scope.
3. Since the compiler can assume exclusive ownership, it can do some performance optimizations that are only possible for non-aliased memory.

If you have an allocatable variable in the main scope. The compiler might rely on the automatic cleanup by the operating system, which will lead to memory leaks reported by valgrind. If you want to get rid of these false-positives you can simply wrap them in a `block`.

### Associate statement

Apart from dynamic memory there is another use-case where one could think that pointers are necessary when coming e.g. from C.
That is defining short names for nested component access like: `chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array`.
This is best done with the `associate` statement

```
associate(M => chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array)
    M(j)
    ! instead of 
    chunks(num_chunks)%ptr%chunk_array(j)
end associate
```

Note that you can associate with variables and parts of arrays; then your association can be a lhs and rhs value.
You can even associate with expressions, then your association can only be a rhs value and you get type deduction for free. So it is far more useful than a pointer.

### Error handling

Regarding error handling there is a nice rule of thumb (if you use a reasonably modern Fortran compiler).
If you don't query the exit status of a call with
`allocate(..., stat=ierr)` the runtime library will kill your process if allocation fails. If you query the exit status, you are responsible yourself to kill it, or do whatever you want.
Since in your case I don't see any necessary logging or cleanup operations, it is actually absolutely valid to not ask for the allocation status.
**But** since you ask for the error stat of the read command, you have to catch errors, that are not EOFs yourself. That was still missing.

### Explicit imports

`use some_module_name` is like `import *` in Python and bad for the same reasons.
Since you only need three identifiers from `iso_fortran_env` I would import them explicitly. Additionally I would add the `intrinsic` qualifier to make it explicit for the human and the compiler that you are using the intrinsic module.

### Require explicit interfaces

It is good that you use `implicit none`. If your compiler supports it, I would additionally write `implicit none(type, external)`.
This will require interfaces for all called procedures. You can read it as "no undeclared variables and no undeclared external procedures".

### Intents and pure/elemental

You have `intent(inout)` at some procedure arguments.
One should always add intents to all arguments. 
Additionally I would separate the declaration of arguments from declaration of local variables.
If a procedure is pure, I would write it explicitly. The compiler will check it for you and it is great to know (code correctness, parallelisation etc.) if a procedure is pure.

### Default initialisation

Pointers should be always initialized. If you don't yet know their target, initialize them to `null()`. If they are not initialized, they are undefined, which is worse than unassociated. If they are a component of a type, you can use default initialization like:

```
type :: ptr_type
    type(my_type), pointer :: x => null()
end type
```

(Although in your case we could get rid of pointers anyway.)

### Consistent spacing

There were some inconsistencies in spacing.
`endtype` vs `end type`

```
        do i = num_chunks, 1, -1
            do j=j, 1, -1
```

### Comments

There were some very redundant comments.
`!!! constants` at parameter variables or `!!! type definitions` at type definitions should be omitted.
You have good names for your procedures, which is always better than comments.

### Naming of types

Since Fortran is not case sensitive, it is impossible to have a `chunk` instance of type `Chunk`. I like the PEP08 guidelines (this is definetely opinion based) from python and you can more or less carry them over. Name types with CamelCase and append `_t`. Then you can have a `chunk` instance of type `Chunk_t`.

### File units

It is generally a bad idea to have a constant for file units. Usually you determine at runtime a free unit and use this one for file opening. Reasonably modern Fortran compilers give you a `freeunit` keyword argument for `open` which does this automatically.

### Open Close pairing

I would indent between pairs of `open` and `close`.

### Loop in normal order

Unless necessary I would always loop in normal order (your deallocation).

## Inquire

You only need to inquire at the end of reading.

## Exit from loop

It is generally better to refactor a `do` loop with exit into a `do while` loop where the condition can be seen in the header of the loop.

## Declaration and initialisation

There is a big surprise in Fortran. A variable that get initialised at declaration becomes automatically save (static if you use C jargon).

```
integer :: n = 0
! is equivalent to
integer, save :: n = 0
```

Unless you really want it to be a save variable (and then I would write it explicitly) it is unfortunately bad to initialise at declaration.

## Size of tmp

In your `ensure_capacity` procedure, the tmp variable was unnecessary large. It is better to have `tmp` with the same size as the `chunks` before it is grown larger

### Alternative new code

```
! take a file and output it to stdout in reverse

program reverse_file_main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: iostat_end, error_unit, output_unit
    implicit none(type, external)

    integer, parameter :: CHUNK_SIZE = 1024, MIN_CHUNKS = 1, IOSTAT_OK = 0

    type :: Chunk_t
        character, allocatable :: chunk_array(:)
    end type

    block
        character(len=1024) :: path, io_msg
        integer :: num_chunks, status, file_id, total_bytes
        type(Chunk_t), allocatable :: chunks(:)


        call get_command_argument(1, path, status=status)
        if (status /= 0) then
            write (error_unit, *) "usage: ./reverse <file>"
            call exit(1)
        end if

        ! open, slurp file and close
        open(newunit=file_id, file=path, access="stream", &
             iostat=status, iomsg=io_msg, status="old")
            if (status /= 0) then
                write (error_unit, *) trim(io_msg)
                call exit(1)
            end if

            allocate(chunks(MIN_CHUNKS))
            call slurp_file(file_id, num_chunks, total_bytes, chunks)
        close(file_id)

        ! output in reverse, and print debug info
        call print_reversed(num_chunks, chunks)
        write (error_unit, *) "reversed ", total_bytes, "bytes"
    end block

contains
    subroutine slurp_file(fid, num_chunks, total_bytes, chunks)
        integer, intent(in) :: fid
        integer, intent(out) :: num_chunks, total_bytes
        type(Chunk_t), allocatable, intent(inout) :: chunks(:)

        integer :: io_status
        character, allocatable :: tmp(:)

        num_chunks = 0
        io_status = 0

        do while (io_status /= iostat_end)
            num_chunks = num_chunks + 1
            call ensure_capacity(num_chunks, chunks)

            allocate(chunks(num_chunks)%chunk_array(CHUNK_SIZE))

            read(fid, iostat=io_status) chunks(num_chunks)%chunk_array
            if (all(io_status /= [IOSTAT_OK, iostat_end])) then
                write(error_unit, *) 'Error in read'
                call exit(1)
            end if

        end do

        inquire(fid, pos=total_bytes)
        total_bytes = total_bytes - 1
        tmp = chunks(num_chunks)%chunk_array(: modulo(total_bytes, CHUNK_SIZE))
        chunks(num_chunks)%chunk_array = tmp
    end subroutine slurp_file


    pure subroutine ensure_capacity(capacity, chunks)
        integer, intent(in) :: capacity
        type(Chunk_t), allocatable, intent(inout) :: chunks(:)

        real, parameter :: grow_factor = 2.0
        type(Chunk_t), allocatable :: tmp(:)

        if (capacity > size(chunks)) then
            tmp = chunks
            deallocate(chunks)
            allocate(chunks(int(grow_factor * size(tmp))))
            chunks(: size(tmp)) = tmp
        end if
    end subroutine ensure_capacity


    subroutine print_reversed(num_chunks, chunks)
        integer, intent(in) :: num_chunks
        type(Chunk_t), intent(in) :: chunks(:)

        integer :: i, j

        do i = num_chunks, 1, -1
            associate(M => chunks(i)%chunk_array)
                do j = size(M), 1, -1
                    call fputc(output_unit, M(j))
                end do
            end associate
        end do
    end subroutine print_reversed

end program reverse_file_main
```